# time duration 3digits:2digits:2digits regular expression

Tags: regex, duration

i have a problem i need get time duration from users as below:
3 digits hours:2 digits minutes:2 digits seconds
for example tv programs duration has 100hours and 50 minutes and 20 seconds

Comment: First of all it is unclear, should've written an example. Second, what have you tried?

Comment: `\d{3}\s?hours\sand\s?[0-5]?\d\s?minutes\sand\s?[0-5]?\d\s?seconds` , https://regex101.com/r/hU3oL4/1

Comment: i need mask as 000:00:00 for duration of tv programs instead of 00:00:00 for time

Comment: What if the use enters one or two digits for hours. Similarly, what should happen if the user enters one digit for the minute and/or the second?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you write, but it looks like php, so here is php:

```
preg_match("/(\d{3}:\d{2}:\d{2})/", $str);
```

But what if the time is 1 hour, 5 minutes and six seconds.
Does it write out as 1:5:6 or 001:05:06?